# XSD: Merge two schemas in one file

Tags: python, xml, xsd, lxml, xsd-validation

Using lxml I am trying to validate XML documents using an XSD.

Problem:
The schema inherits from another schema, and (probably) because the files are not local, I get an error message.

Schema source:
https://github.com/IHEC/ihec-ecosystems/tree/master/schemas/xml

Schemas used:

- SRA.experiment.xsd
- SRA.sample.xsd

Both inherit from:

- SRA.common.xsd

Question: Is it possible to merge **SRA.experiment.xsd** and **SRA.sample.xsd** with **SRA.common.xsd**, respectively?

This is an example when using one of the schemas:

```
import lxml.etree
from urllib.request import urlopen

xsd = urlopen("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IHEC/ihec-ecosystems/master/schemas/xml/SRA.sample.xsd").read()
schema = lxml.etree.XMLSchema(lxml.etree.fromstring(xsd))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "delme.py", line 5, in <module>
    schema = lxml.etree.XMLSchema(lxml.etree.fromstring(xsd))
  File "src/lxml/xmlschema.pxi", line 88, in lxml.etree.XMLSchema.__init__
lxml.etree.XMLSchemaParseError: complex type 'SampleType', attribute 'base': The QName value '{SRA.common}ObjectType' does not resolve to a(n) simple type definition., line 17
```

Comment: So you get an error message, but you don't want to tell us what it says?

Comment: Basically, you should be able to merge the two schema documents if and only if they use the same `targetNamespace`.